# Haskell typeclass hierarchy issue

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a scenario that involves type classes and I'm not quite sure how to go about solving it.

I have

```
class Event a where
     timestamp :: a -> UTCTime
     rawData :: a -> ByteString

class Something a where
    something :: a -> SomethingElse
```

In my code, I want to create an object that implements both Event and Something. However, in certain cases, the function something is going to need the return from a call to rawData to construct the SomethingElse object. I was wondering if there was to structure these type classes to be able to build a function like

```
convert :: (Event a, Event b, Something b) => a -> b
```

being able to call convert x :: (Instance of something) in order to convert, a bit like how binary get is used.

I realize that this is a rather vague description, but please let me know if I can add anything else.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but in order for `convert` to be able to return a value of any `Event` & `Something` type, you need a way to construct a value of any `Event` & `Something` type while knowing only that the type belongs to those two classes.  You could give one of the classes a method like `unraw :: ByteString -> a` or, if such a method would require utilizing features of both classes for some reason, make a new class that inherits both `Event` & `Something` and has the desired constructor.

Comment: you have to give some context to `SomethingElse`, way not just `ByteString`?

Comment: Pretty much SomethingElse is just a deserialized object where the bytestring is the serialized version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In type class Something you need to make sure that the type a has implemented type class Event, hence the definition of Something becomes:

```
class Event a => Something a where
     something :: a -> SomethingElse
```

Comment: How would I abstract it out if Something doesn't always need an event. Lets say only in certain cases a Something is constructed by an event. How would I organize that hierarchy? I'm not that familiar with standard Object oriented practices.

Comment: In that case you can remove the (Event a) restriction from Something type class and put this restriction on a new method inside Something class.. somethingFromEvent ... this method will create something from event and the parameter to this method must have a instance of Event class.